# css block within block float right

Tags: html, css

Most embarassed to be coming to others for help with this if i'm honest, but i have reached my 1 1/2 hr sanity limit.

I want to have a block (with a coloured border) postioned on the right of the page with width suitable to the text content + padding.  I want it to reserve the whole row for itself without other element below creeping into the space left on the left.

I realised early on that any width = 100% would mean that the whole row would have the border rather then just the content I wanted and various experiments with float lead to the space on the left being occupied with elements creeping into the space from below.  To remedy i have created a containing block with 100% width and display = block and put the border round the child div.  Still doesn't work! I have the `#costblock` being the container and the `#costs` being the content:

```
#costsblock {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
}

#costs  {
  border: 1px solid #008eaf;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

<div id="costsblock">
<div id="costs">The text</div>
</div>
```

I have experimented with virtually all combinations of display and width and float on both the parent and the child and nothing works - I either get the whole row surrounded by the border or, if I dare to put a float: right anywhere at all then the space on the left gets filled wih elements creeping in from below.

I think that I need to contrain the child width to what is necessary to hold the text only, but I can't seem to get that working!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able do solve this by changing `display` to `inline-block` for the child and then setting `text-align` to right for the parent element:

```
#costsblock {    
  text-align:right;
}

#costs  {
  border: 1px solid #008eaf;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

It is not necessary to set `display:block` for a `div` element, since they are defined as block level elements by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with the extra container element did not work, because `#post` is a `block` element, and as such still takes the whole width (unless you tell it otherwise). Anyway, there is no need for an extra element.

> I want it to reserve the whole row for itself without other element below creeping into the space left on the left.

Then all you have to do is `clear` the `float` on the next element:

```css
#costs {
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid #008eaf;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#next {
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="costs">The text</div>

<div id="next">I am the next element following the floating one.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for the kind help

Answer (score 1):

You can use float, but be sure to have an element that has `clear: both` below the floating element to prevent any elements 'creeping into the space left'.

For example:

```
<div id="costsblock">
    <div id="costs">The text</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/xxc9nk1t/